# How does Mike Bostock's (D3js's creator) pan & zoom example work?

Tags: d3.js

I'm having a hard time understanding this example:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4e3925cdc804db257a86fdef3a032a45

I understand the general concept, all the points in the graph are put into a `svg` `g`-element, which is useful because now you can apply a transform on the group and have all the points scale accordingly. This transforms the whole coordinate system that these points are in. But this does not matter for the mouse-coordinate that is passed along for panning because those coordinates come from an invisible `rect` in the `svg` that does not get transformed.

What I don't understand is this:

```
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .call(d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
        .on("zoom", zoomed));

function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

Is the .call a member function of the default `svg`-rectangle? What does it do here? `And d3.zoom` is according to the documentation a 'behaviour'. What does that mean and how does the coupling between these two work here? And what is the purpose of the function `.on`, which gets passed `'zoom'`? I assume it's for passing the browser event of zooming on an element to the event handler `zoomed`. But then how does panning get handled here? And is it just me or would it have had more sense to have `.scaleExtent` and `.on` as parameters of `d3.zoom()`?

Answer (score 0):

The rect **receives** the browser zoom events.

The **zoomed** function applies the transform to the **g** element

Note we have the **rect** after the **g** otherwise the rect would behind the g not receiving events.

`svg
- g
- rect`